# Spans generated with Renderer2 and appended are appended in incorrect order

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using `setInterval` to print text to a div similar to an RPG. If the div is navigated away from, the text is stored and kept so that it can be preserved and the print resumed once the div is visible again.

The stored text, if any, is appended to the empty div first, then the print is resumed. However, the newly generated text appears before the previously appended text, with it seeming to appear in the correct spot at the front without staying there.

I know this is very vague, but I have a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-kt9sdt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) created with all of the code inside to show what I mean, as that is a lot easier to see than me explaining it here.

I simply want the text to append as intended - after the stored content instead of at the front. In the StackBlitz start the print, then toggle visibility back and forth to see it in action.